# SqlMembershipProvider Membership.GetUser by name failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, sqlmembershipprovider, .net

**The problem**
Membership.GetUser works fine if I use the GUID, but fails if I try it without parameters or with the name:

```
//This works and adds records to aspnet_user & aspnet_Membership tables
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(_name, _pwd, _email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus); 

//These fail with an InvalidCastException
MembershipUser membershipUser2 = Membership.GetUser(_name, true);
MembershipUser membershipUser3 = Membership.GetUser();

//If I go look up the GUID for this user (userId), this works!
MembershipUser membershipUser4 = Membership.GetUser(new Guid("E1428CD3-CF17-494E-AB77-CF8F6010F585"), true);
```

**Other Mysteries**

```
//This works
Int32 count = Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline();    

//this fails (but totalRecords has the right value)
Int32 totalRecords;
MembershipUserCollection col = Membership.GetAllUsers(0,100, out totalRecords);
```

**The Setup**

- MVC
- .NET 4.0
- Default SQL Membership Provider (no custom or overrides)

ex:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="SqlProvider" 
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
           connectionStringName="MyDB" 
           enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
           enablePasswordReset="true" 
           requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
           applicationName="myapp" 
           requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
           passwordFormat="Hashed" 
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
           minRequiredPasswordLength="2" 
           minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
           passwordAttemptWindow="10"
           passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

- Standard aspnet_* database tables with no customization or extra keys
- aspnet_Membership_GetAllUsers runs fine manually from the DB.  Redirected output shows the expected results are being returned
- aspnet_Membership_GetUserByName is working as well from the DB

**Exception Details**

```
Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_SqlGuid()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
```

**Thoughts**

It's almost like there's something wrong inside the Membership.GetUser method.  I reflected out the code for the System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetUser for my System.Web.dll (version 4.0) and I get the following:

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
  SecUtility.CheckParameter(ref username, true, false, true, 256, "username");
  SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader) null;
  try
  {
    SqlConnectionHolder connectionHolder = (SqlConnectionHolder) null;
    try
    {
      connectionHolder = SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(this._sqlConnectionString, true);
      this.CheckSchemaVersion(connectionHolder.Connection);
      SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetUserByName", connectionHolder.Connection);
      sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout;
      sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(this.CreateInputParam("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, (object) this.ApplicationName));
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(this.CreateInputParam("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, (object) username));
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(this.CreateInputParam("@UpdateLastActivity", SqlDbType.Bit, (object) (bool) (userIsOnline ? 1 : 0)));
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(this.CreateInputParam("@CurrentTimeUtc", SqlDbType.DateTime, (object) DateTime.UtcNow));
      SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
      sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
      reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
      if (!reader.Read())
        return (MembershipUser) null;
      string nullableString1 = this.GetNullableString(reader, 0);
      string nullableString2 = this.GetNullableString(reader, 1);
      string nullableString3 = this.GetNullableString(reader, 2);
      bool boolean1 = reader.GetBoolean(3);
      DateTime creationDate = reader.GetDateTime(4).ToLocalTime();
      DateTime lastLoginDate = reader.GetDateTime(5).ToLocalTime();
      DateTime lastActivityDate = reader.GetDateTime(6).ToLocalTime();
      DateTime lastPasswordChangedDate = reader.GetDateTime(7).ToLocalTime();
      Guid guid = reader.GetGuid(8);
      bool boolean2 = reader.GetBoolean(9);
      DateTime lastLockoutDate = reader.GetDateTime(10).ToLocalTime();
      return new MembershipUser(this.Name, username, (object) guid, nullableString1, nullableString2, nullableString3, boolean1, boolean2, creationDate, lastLoginDate, lastActivityDate, lastPasswordChangedDate, lastLockoutDate);
    }
    finally
    {
      if (reader != null)
        reader.Close();
      if (connectionHolder != null)
        connectionHolder.Close();
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

**Next Step**

I'm hoping to get some direction from the SO crowd on where I should go next.  I figure I could either override this method and put together my own provider just to debug it, or I could just go around the darned thing and call out to the DB myself directly.  This seems like a lot of heartache from some basic DB CRUD.

**Current Status**

- 3/5/2013: I discovered this morning that my `aspnet_Users` table has the `UserId` as an `nvarchar(256)` instead of a `uniqueidentifier`.  Perhaps the `SqlDataReader.GetGuid()` is choking there.  I'll run some tests this evening to see if that's the problem.  I'm wondering if my table structure is outdated, because online documentation shows this field as a `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: How does it fail? Exception Details please.

Comment: Added exception details.  The line: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i) sure seems odd.

Comment: Also, if you are going to "reflect-out" / reverse-engineer / decompile-for-insight the code, you should look at the method GetUser() on the static Membership class  -- Membership.GetUser() -- it is THERE where assumptions are being made about the current user's identity.  GetUser() assumes that it is retrieving detail about the CURRENT USER in a web application

Comment: Good idea, I tried that.  The Membership class has this code:

`return Membership.GetUser(Membership.GetCurrentUserName(), true);`

Executing the following in the Immediate window yielded the expected username:

`System.Web.Security.Membership.GetCurrentUserName() //Good result`

However...

`System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser( System.Web.Security.Membership.GetCurrentUserName(), true)`

Still seems to be returning the InvalidCast. :(

Comment: Get us that stack trace if you can... specicallly Invalid cast details.

Comment: I added the stack trace to the Exception Details section above.  It's quite short:

`Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_SqlGuid()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)`

Comment: I looks like the aspnet_Users table has the UserId as nvarchar(256) instead of uniqueidentifier.  This may be the problem.  I'll run some tests this evening to confirm.

Comment: I assure you that there isn't a problem with the methods in question.  If anything your expecting the wrong results from them.  The exception is telling you exactly where its failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

My aspnet_User and aspnet_Membership tables had the `UserId` set to a type of `nvarchar(256)`.

**Discussion**

This appears to have been causing the error during the following line from the SqlMembershipProvider.GetUser method:

```
Guid guid = reader.GetGuid(8);
```

I ran aspnet_regsql.exe from both .NET frameworks 2 and 4, and both set the UserId to a uniqueidentifier, leading me to think I did not (after all) have a standard ASPNET DB.

A little digging in the project's history reveals that this membership database was originally generated via a **custom provider** for **MySql**.  I can only conclude that it was never regenerated when we switched back to the default provider.

Thanks to everyone for their feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `membership.CurrentUserName()`? You can just use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;`